# Application routing depending on different domains and subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I have this PHP website hosted in a remote server. I have at least 2 applications running on it.

It responds through the domain `x.com` that points to root. `x.com/y` is one of the applications and I want it to be accessed both by `y.x.com`, as a subdomain and by `y.com`, as another domain

y.com and y.x.com will point to root and I need a way to redirect to x.com/y, preferably without changing the address

Any suggestiong? 
I am using Codeigniter framework